# Passing variable from Ajax to PHP in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am developing a WordPress plugin and I am trying to pass a variable from ajax to a php file. Both files are inside my plugin folder. The js file is running but when I fire the ajax function, it seems that is not sending a post.

**Plugin structure:**

- -plugin folder

  --ajax.js

  --folder/example.php

This is my ajax.js

```
// using jQuery ajax
// send the text with PHP
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/absoluteurlpluginfolder/folder/example.php",
        data: {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
                },
            // dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
              console.log('Connection success.');
              // console.log(data);
            }
          });
```

And this is my example.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

  alert($whatever);

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

I have two problems:

1. I cannot see that example.php is receiving anything
2. How could I use a relative URL to connect with my PHP file? When I try such as 'url: "folder/example.php",' it seems that it starts with "http://localhost/my-wp-project/wp-admin/" and not in my plugin folder, and fails.

Comment: If you run something like Chrome Debugger, you'll be able to see the ajax request and response under the network tab, which would confirm the call is being made and help see the response.

Comment: @JECarterII I just check and it is sending it correctly. Still I cannot see the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main problem was that I need to add "wp_enqueue_script" and "wp_localize_script". However, I am working in the development of a **TinyMCE** plugin inside WordPress.

That means that although the JS file is already include, it is not working when I add "wp_enqueue_script" and "wp_localize_script". Why? I do not know but the strange thing is that I made it working with another line.

```
  wp_register_script( 'linked-plugin-script', null);
```

I have tried with different versions, and the minimum necessary to work is this one above. I can put the URL, version, jquery dependency and false or true. All of them work.

So at the end this is my code and is working.
This is the plugin.php

```
// Include the JS for TinyMCE
function linked_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['linked'] = plugins_url( '/public/js/tinymce/plugins/linked/plugin.js',__FILE__ );
    return $plugin_array;
}

// Add the button key for address via JS
function linked_tinymce_button( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'linked_button_key' );
    return $buttons;
}


// Enqueue the plugin to manage data via AJAX
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {

  wp_register_script( 'linked-plugin-script', null);

  wp_enqueue_script( 'linked-plugin-script');

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'linked-plugin-script', 'ajax_object', array(
                                                        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                                                        'whatever' => '' )
                                                      );
}


// Same handler function...
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
  function my_action() {
    global $wpdb;

    $whatever = strtoupper($_POST['whatever']);
    echo $whatever;

    wp_die();
}
```

And this is the plugin of TinyMCE in JavaScript

```
// JavaScript file for TinyMCE Linked Plugin
//
//
//
( function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'linked', function( editor, url ) {

        // Add a button that opens a window
        editor.addButton( 'linked_button_key', {
            // Button name and icon
            text: 'Semantic Notation',
            icon: false,
            // Button fnctionality
            onclick: function() {

              // get raw text to variable content
              var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'text'});

              // using jQuery ajax
              // send the text to textrazor API with PHP
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                data: { 'action': 'my_action',
                          'whatever': ajax_object.whatever = content
                       },
                beforeSend: function() {
                  console.log('before send..');
                 },
                success: function(response){
                  console.log('Success the result is '+response);
                }
              });








            } // onclick function

        } ); // TinyMCE button

    } ); // tinymce.PluginManager

} )(); // function
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? This is the best tutorial. But you have missed a few things:

1. You should set global js variable with `wp_localize_script()` function. Like

   `wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );`
2. Replace your url in JS to `ajax_object.ajax_url`.

IF you wanna work ajax with `wp_ajax` hooks - you should send all your requests do `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. You can get this url by `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');`.

Comment: Yes I have been working with the example of that page but still I cannot understand it. I will check what you mention, thanks!

Comment: You missed `wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
 wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
` You should include your script with `wp_enqueue_script` and then use `wp_localize_script` to your file.

Comment: Did you sorted out? @AdriánVázquez

Comment: Do you mean to add that in my php file or my plugin file.

Comment: @JordiVicens not yet

Comment: Looks. You have plugin file, where you include your js file. Right? looks reference. Section with `Separate JavaScript File` title. And you have file with php hook? Have you included your file to plugin file?

Comment: There are two different files, one is the plugin file where I enqueue the js file which is working. But I am trying to reach another php file.

Comment: Ok, its good practice. `include` or `require` functions helps you.